# ABAP Query an XML file with xpath

Tags: xml, xpath, abap

My goal is to query an XML document by XPath. I couldn't find an option to do this with the `if_ixml` framework. I have found this [article](https://www.abapforum.com/forum/viewtopic.php?t=18667) (sadly it's in German) about querying an XSLT file with XPath using `CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR` but that doesn't seem to work anymore, it seems like `->run( space )` is the problem, and I get this short dump with message:

> No valid XSLT program supplied

Even while trying with the wrapper class `CL_PROXY_XPATH` in the code below, I get the same short dump.

It feels like that there must be a class to do exactly this.

```
DATA(s) = |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><codedb><cl id="3">|
       && |<enumeration value="AAA"/><enumeration value="AAB"/><enumeration value="AAC"/>|
       && |<enumeration value="AAD"/><enumeration value="AAE"/>|
       && |</cl></codedb>|.

data(xpp) = new cl_proxy_xpath( ).
xpp->set_source_string( s ).
xpp->run( expression = '//cl[@id=3]/enumeration[@value=$codeValue3]' ).     "<== SHORTDUMP
data(nodes) = xpp->get_nodes( ).
"Calculate all values from the nodes
data(node) = nodes->get_next( ).
while node is bound.
    write: / node->get_value( ).
    node = nodes->get_next( ).
endwhile.
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are two issues in your code:

- One is that your XPath expression contains `$codeValue3` which results in a `No valid XSLT program supplied` short dump.
- One is due to the node in your input XML, `<enumeration value="AAC"/>`, which contains an empty "text value" (it doesn't contain the attributes), so the method `get_value` returns an empty value.

When it's corrected, both `CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR` and `CL_PROXY_XPATH` should work fine.

Here is a working code tested in ABAP 7.52, one with `CL_PROXY_XPATH` and one with `CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR`:

```
DATA(s) = |<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><codedb><cl id="3">|
       && |<enumeration value="AAA"/><enumeration value="AAB"/>|
       && |<enumeration value="AAC">AAC value</enumeration>|          "<====
       && |<enumeration value="AAD"/><enumeration value="AAE"/>|
       && |</cl></codedb>|.
DATA(expression) = `//cl[@id=3]/enumeration[@value="AAC"]`.

WRITE: / 'CL_PROXY_XPATH:'.
DATA(xpp) = NEW cl_proxy_xpath( ).
xpp->set_source_string( s ).
DATA(nodes) = xpp->get_nodes( expression = expression ).
DATA(node) = nodes->get_next( ).
WHILE node IS BOUND.
  WRITE node->get_value( ). " Get text value of node (not attributes)
  node = nodes->get_next( ).
ENDWHILE.

WRITE: / 'CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR:'.
DATA(xpp2) = NEW cl_xslt_processor( ).
xpp2->set_source_string( s ).
xpp2->set_expression( expression = expression ).
xpp2->run( ' ' ).
DATA(nodes2) = xpp2->get_nodes( ).
DO nodes2->get_length( ) TIMES.
  DATA(node2) = nodes2->get_item( sy-index - 1 ).
  WRITE node2->get_value( ).
ENDDO.
```

Output:

```
CL_PROXY_XPATH: AAC value
CL_XSLT_PROCESSOR: AAC value
```